# React context: how to transfer function?

Tags: reactjs

How can I pass the addToCard function from the ShoppingBasketProvider component via context to run it in another component? And how right is it in the component to keep the functions in the component using the context. Thank you for your help.

I have a component:

```
export const ShoppingBasketContext = React.createContext();

export default class ShoppingBasketProvider extends Component {


  addToCard = (event) => {
    console.log(event);
  }

  render() {
    const { shoppingBasketItems } = `this.state`;

    return (
      <ShoppingBasketContext.Provider
        value={{
          shoppingBasketItems,

        }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </ShoppingBasketContext.Provider>
    )
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass on the function as a value to Context provider.

```
export const ShoppingBasketContext = React.createContext();

export default class ShoppingBasketProvider extends Component {


  addToCard = (event) => {
    console.log(event);
  }

  render() {
    const { shoppingBasketItems } = `this.state`;

    return (
      <ShoppingBasketContext.Provider
        value={{
          shoppingBasketItems,
          addToCard: this.addToCard
        }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </ShoppingBasketContext.Provider>
    )
 }
}
```

You can keep function in the ContextProvider and allow other component to use the function from context and call it.

Comment: Thanks. Its work. I can writing this in another method? Just interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Context API is a provider from which we can share data among components. And obviously, we can pass the functions in similar way:

```
value={{
   shoppingBasketItems,
   addToCard: this.addToCard
}}
```

But I would not suggest you to go with this approach. Instead, you can have a separate file let's call it `Util.js` and inside that export the required functions and you can use that where ever you want:

**Util.js**

```
export const required_function = () => {
  //...
}
```

**Component.js**

```
import { required_function } from 'Util'
//... required_function() ...
```